# CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I am working with some code for location update. The same code works in different projects or in a new project but whenever I run it in an existing project `startUpdatingLocation` is not being called. So user location can not be shown. I mean blue dot is not there. Here is the code I use:

in .h file

```
@interface CheckIn : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, YCameraViewControllerDelegate>

{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapCheckinAcity;
```

in .m file

in viewDidLoad

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I am setting up all settings and working on real device. As I told this is working in new project but not in existing one. I am really confused at the moment.

Comment: Check the privacy->Location settings for your app.  Once an app has been denied location access the system won't prompt the user again.  Have you implemented the `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` location manager delegate method?  What value are you getting for the authorisation status?

Comment: In same app I have another map which was implemented before like over a year ago. It is working properly with the same code.

Comment: What status do you get in `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` ?

Comment: it is not even called.

Comment: Then set a breakpoint in your `viewDidLoad` where you create the location manager and verify that it is being called.  Your code looks right, but if your delegate methods aren't getting called you have a problem somewhere else

Comment: it says "locationManager CLLocationManager * nil" after self.locationManager.delegate = self; but i use same code new project and it works. also existing code in different class in same project works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56512/discussion-between-paulw11-and-gbesler).